# In pulsar bookeeper need to change the journalDirectory from one mount point to another

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-pulsar, pulsar, apache-bookkeeper

In pulsar bookeeper need to change the journalDirectory from one mount point to another

There are three bookeeper running and in bookkeeper.conf ,the
journalDirectory=/data1/bookkeeper/journal need to change to data which is seperate mount point with higher capacity.

I stopped the bookkeeper services and tried changing from /data1/bookkeeper/journal to /data/bookkeeper/journal ,tried copying /data1 contains to /data but no luck

4
bookieHost: "IP:3181"
journalDir: "/data1/bookkeeper/journal"
ledgerDirs: "1\t/data/bookkeeper/ledgers"
instanceId: "bace4435-c729-4494-89f6-c14b1ab33a98"

to

4
bookieHost: "IP:3181"
journalDir: "/data/bookkeeper/journal"
ledgerDirs: "1\t/data/bookkeeper/ledgers"
instanceId: "bace4435-c729-4494-89f6-c14b1ab33a98"

tried changing in version file ,removed the one bookkeeper from the list and restarted but no luck the bookkeeper goes to fatal state